# How can I remove the “Checkout” url from top links in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I'm using Magento 1.7 (latest version) and I want to remove the "Checkout" link only from the top navigation link.

I have tried

```
<remove name="checkout_cart_link" />
```

but it removes the cart link too, which I dont want to remove.

Comment: rather than giving minus vote,someone give me answer,if have idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Direct checkout.xml on never update avoide changes on core files**

```
<reference name="top.links">
            <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
                <action method="addCartLink"></action>
                <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
            </block>
</reference>
```

> **comment this code or remove**

```
<!--<action method="addCheckoutLink">< /action>-->
```

**Using Local.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="top.links">
          <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>
            <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link_custom">
                <action method="addCartLink"></action>
                <!--<action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>-->
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**OR**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
    <reference name="top.links">
            <remove name="checkout_cart_link" />
            <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link_custom">
                <action method="addCartLink"></action>
            </block>
          </reference>
        </default>
    </layout>
```

Comment: Matt Byrne's answer below is the best practice way, not this. This answer requires creating a duplicate override in your own theme of checkout.xml rather than using local.xml which is bad practice because overriding native layouts in your theme means you will have big problems com upgrades!

Comment: This is not even an answer, and should not be the accepted answer to this question. Sure, it is the source code that adds the link in the first place, but it does not explain at all how to remove the link. As BenLeah states in the above comment, editing checkout.xml directly does not follow upgrade compatible practices for Magento. Anyone reading this should refer to Matt Byrne's answer.

Answer (score 10):

Old post, but for others searching you don't want to be copying and editing `checkout.xml` and want to avoid adding custom code.

To do this via `local.xml`, remove the block like the asker tried, then add the cart link back in (the name of the new block is slightly different).

```
        <reference name="top.links">
            <remove name="checkout_cart_link" />
            <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link_custom">
                <action method="addCartLink"></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

Credit to this post which gave the idea of removing and adding back in: http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/editing-magentos-top-links-the-better-way

Answer (score 0):

The top links are done a bit differently to other things, rather than each link being a block you can remove in itself, there is one parent block named `top.links` which contains all of the links, and in one case there is a child block as you have found named `checkout_cart_link` which contains the links for the checkout and cart.

Links are added into the `top.links` by calls to block methods in your layout files and this is done across a number of different layout files.  The block method called on the `top.links` block is `addLink()` and you can find this method in class `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links`.  The child block `checkout_cart_links` also defines 2 more block methods `addCartLink()` and `addCheckoutLink()` which can be found in class `Mage_Checkout_Block_Links`.

Unfortunately removing already added links is one of only a few things you can't do by default from your own layout file as there is no `removeLink()` or similar block method.  This means that to remove the checkout link, you have a couple of choices

- Add your own `removeCheckoutLink()` block method into a block you create and reference it from your own layout file.  This would need to reverse what the `addCheckoutLink()` block method did.  Note that a `local.xml` layout file, and layout files you define in your own module will affect the layout *after* all core modules, so you could be sure your method would run after the `addCheckoutLink()` method
- The other easier option, but one that leaves the standard checkout layout file edited is to copy the `checkout.xml` layout file into your current theme layout folder if it isn't already there and remove the `addCheckoutLink()` action node inside the `checkout_cart_link` block.